# rest_framework.response return string? python

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

can you help me please?

I have the following code

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
......
return Response(data=str({'id': pk}), status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN, content_type='application/json')
```

Return
**"**{'id': '54fa0000-1cdd-4c6d-83d7-ab19a7f11944'}**"**

How can I return without quotes at the beginning and at the end?
{'id': '54fa0000-1cdd-4c6d-83d7-ab19a7f11944'}

Answer (score 0):

rest_framework's Response returns json by default, so:

```py
return Response({'id': pk}, status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
```

Comment: Hi Nicolas, run it.

return Response({'id': pk}, status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
Response
{"id": "54fa0000-1cdd-4c6d-83d7-ab19a7f11944"}
but now it comes out with double quotes and I need it without double quotes example:

{'id': '54fa0000-1cdd-4c6d-83d7-ab19a7f11944'}

Comment: It is a json standard response, it has to be double quotes

Comment: Hi Goku, are you sure you need single quotes? This is unusual as valid JSON uses double quotes.

Comment: I was performing the tests (TDD) and a test validates that json. I asked them to validate the test, but I'm still looking for a solution :P

Answer (score 0):

run it.

```
return Response({'id': pk}, status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
```

Response

```
{"id": "54fa0000-1cdd-4c6d-83d7-ab19a7f11944"}
```

but now it comes out with double quotes and I need it without double  quotes
example:

```
{'id': '54fa0000-1cdd-4c6d-83d7-ab19a7f11944'}
```